# Go to previous page in a session

Tags: php

I'm working on a school assignment where I have to translate words. On a seperate page I have to show whether a word is right or wrong and there needs to be a button to go back to the previous page so you can continue with the next word.

But how do I go back to the previous page without losing my session?

```
<a href="window.history.go(-1);">Previous page</a>
```

Gives me 'Object not found'. I'm working with Xampp.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$dutch = array('boom', 'kaas', 'hond', 'huis', 'auto');
$english = array('tree', 'cheese', 'dog', 'house', 'car');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
{
  $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
  $_SESSION['correct'] = 0;
  $_SESSION['incorrect'] = 0;
}
?>

<html>    
<body>
<p>Translate the following word: <strong><?php echo ucfirst($dutch[$_SESSION['counter']]); ?></strong></p>
<form action="opdracht3.11b.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="answer" />
<input type="submit" value="Check!" />
<p>Progress: <?php echo $_SESSION['counter']."/".count($dutch); ?><br>
Correct words: <?php echo $_SESSION['correct']; ?><br>
Incorrect words: <?php echo $_SESSION['incorrect']; ?></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code of the second page:

```
<?php
session_start();

$dutch = array('boom', 'kaas', 'hond', 'huis', 'auto');
$english = array('tree', 'cheese', 'dog', 'house', 'car');

if($_POST['answer'] == ($english[$_SESSION['counter']]))
    {
       $_SESSION['correct'] = $_SESSION['correct'] + 1;
       $_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter'] + 1;
       echo "Correct!";
    }
    else
    {
      $_SESSION['incorrect'] = $_SESSION['incorrect'] + 1;
      $_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter'] + 1;
       echo "Incorrect!";
    }
?>

<html>
<?php echo "<br/>";?>
<a href="window.history.go(-1);">Previous page</a>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT I:**
**print_r($_SESSION)** gives me:

```
    Array
(
    [form] => Array
        (
            [textfield1] => 1
            [textfield2] => 2
            [textfield3] => 3
            [submit] => Verzenden
        )

    [cijfers] => Array
        (
        )

    [counter] => 0
    [teller] => 0
    [goed] => 0
    [fout] => 0
    [back] => /opdracht3.11b.php
    [correct] => 0
    [incorrect] => 0
)
```

I changed teller to counter, goed to correct and fout to incorrect before posting, so don't mind those. When I enter a correct translation and use the previous page button in my browser, this is happens:

```
Array
(
    [form] => Array
        (
            [textfield1] => 1
            [textfield2] => 2
            [textfield3] => 3
            [submit] => Verzenden
        )

    [cijfers] => Array
        (
        )

    [counter] => 1
    [teller] => 0
    [goed] => 0
    [fout] => 0
    [back] => /opdracht3.11b.php
    [correct] => 1
    [incorrect] => 0
)
```

---

**EDIT II:**

I changed:

```
// Change #1
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')

// To:
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')

// Change #2
<html>
<?php echo "<br/>";?>
<a href="window.history.go(-1);">Previous page</a>
</html>

// To:
echo "<p><a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\" title=\"Return to previous page\">Go back</a></p>";
```

And it kind of works now, at least the session does. For counter, correct and incorrect I'm getting undefined index errors. Think I need to play with isset() to get rid of those errors..?

Comment: What happens when you `print_r($_SESSION);` ? I'm guessing at your sessions not being set.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using HTTP_REFERER by replacing this:

```
<?php echo "<br/>";?>
<a href="window.history.go(-1);">Previous page</a>
</html>
```

With this?

```
<html>
<?php echo "<br/>";?>
<a href=<?php echo '"'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'"';?>>Previous page</a>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this

window.history.back();

Please have a try like this..

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp